# Can't change NavigationView background

Tags: android, background, navigationview

I'm trying to change background to DarkGray for NavigationView in android, but nothing is working for me. I don't understand why.
I tried many things. This is my last code but. it's still not working

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorDarkGray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">
```

[This is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wEa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the background color of the `NavigationView`, I changed the theme from light to dark theme.

I created custom themes and applied to the menifest. This way I changed the background color of the `NavigationView`.

Comment: My solution is working in other project. Just I don't understand why it's not working here.